# Null values inserted in sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, ios5, sqlite, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

I'm working wit an app that takes strings from the user and saves it to the database. After checking the code again and again, the strings aren't getting into the database. For example if I add a string like "abc", I'm getting the message STRING ADDED but on opening the database in sqlite manager, null is inserted in place of abc. Can anyone guide me? I'm using xcode 4.2 and developing for iPhone.

Comment: You need to provide sample code for others to really see the problem.

Comment: That usually happens if you have set the data type of your colum to integer and you try to insert a string. Be sure to check that.

Comment: Solved it!! I just added     NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO strings (string) VALUES (\"%@\")",textfield.text];
Instead of     NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO strings (string) VALUES (?)",textfield.text];